# How to pass variadic arguments while adding another one in Scala?

Tags: scala, arguments, parameter-passing

Consider these methods:

```
def clearlnOut(coll : Any*)
{
  clearOut(coll:_*,"\n") // error
}
def clearOut(coll : Any*)
{
  ...
```

The compiler says:

> error: no `: _*' annotation allowed here (such annotations are only allowed in arguments to *-parameters)

Now I am puzzled. It is clear case of using variadic arguments, so how to pass such augmented "collection" properly?

Comment: This deserves a /r/lolscala subreddit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
def clearlnOut(coll : Any*) {
  clearOut(coll ++ "\n")
}
```

UPDATE: much better version suggested by *@Rex Kerr* (see comment below):

```
def clearlnOut(coll : Any*) {
  clearOut((coll :+ "\n"): _*)
}
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. I thought variadic arguments (when passing) have to be unfolded.

Comment: Do you really want `++`?  That'll add `\n` as a character (and would add "foo" as three separate one character elements).  Seems like `:+` is the way to go. Also, don't you want to append `: _*` to it?  Otherwise you get a `Seq[Seq[Any]]`, an extra level of nesting.

Comment: @RexKerr: Thank you for your suggestions, you are absolutely right. I added your solution to my answer, however you should probably add a separate answer to give you a full credit for this.

Comment: I don't need credit.  I just want the right answer out there.